# Почему перестал открываться сайт?

Tags: http, провайдер, сеть, dns

Очень интересная ситуация.

С недавнего времени, как два дня назад, перестал открываться определенный сайт, который наиболее часто я посещаю, причем во всех браузерах.
Например, в Chrome при открытии отображается системная ошибка и сообшение:

```
Веб-страница недоступна
```

> Код ошибки: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Все остальные сайты открываются, почему-то только этот...

Замечу, что доступа к роутеру для его перезагрузки не имею. Только доступ к WiFi по паролю.

Пробовал следующие шаги:

1. Очистка кэш браузера
2. Проверка в
       разных браузерах, переустановка
       браузера.
3. Сброс DNS кеша через
       командную строку
4. Проверка компьютеров на вирусы
5. Просмотр файла
       vhosts в `system32/drivers/`
6. Перезагрузка компьютера
7. Команда ping отдает сообщение - узел не найден
8. Переподключался к роутеру

**Замечание:** сайт открывается через proxy servers.

Кто может предположить, в чем дело и как разрешить проблему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня такое было на стороне роутера asus rt n13u. Я бы попробовал

1. Подключиться с другого устройства к той же сети, чтобы исключить проблему на стороне устройства (компьютера)
2. Вручную прописать dns-сервера (какой-нибудь 8.8.8.8) и посмотреть, что выйдет

> Просмотр файла vhosts в system32/drivers/

еще неплохо бы заглянуть в system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: C другого устройства пробовал - тот же результат. В hosts ничего нет, кроме localhost. DNS - вы имеете ввиду прописать в настройках TCP/IP?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, да

Comment: Ооо. Вы гений, прописал для TCP/IP(4) вашу рекомендацию и заработал. Как это объяснить?

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk тем, что выдаваемый по умолчанию сетью dns-сервер барахлит

Comment: или на нем поправлены dns записи.